# Pytesseract adding extra characters

Tags: python, tesseract, opencv, python-tesseract

So, I have been experimenting with Pytesseract for a short while. I want it to read a small part of the screen, and return what it says. The image I want it to read is:[image: image: "Done Canceling"]

This is my code currently (following an Youtube video):

```
import cv2
import pytesseract as tes

tes.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

img = cv2.imread("DoneCheck.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
G = []
print(tes.image_to_string(img))
G.append(tes.image_to_string(img))
print(G)

hImg, wImg,_ = img.shape
boxes = tes.image_to_boxes(img)


for b in boxes.splitlines():
    print(b)
    b = b.split(' ')
    #print(b)
    x,y,w,h = int(b[1]), int(b[2]), int(b[3]), int(b[4])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, hImg-y), (w, hImg - h), (0, 0, 255), 1)



cv2.imshow("result", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

And this is what it prints:

"
Done Canceling,
♀,
['Done Canceling\n\x0c'],
D 12 8 23 19 0,
o 20 8 29 19 0,
n 25 8 34 17 0,
e 36 8 55 17 0,
C 62 8 72 19 0,
a 74 8 81 17 0,
n 78 5 88 20 0,
c 84 8 93 17 0,
e 95 8 102 17 0,
l 105 8 113 17 0,
i 115 8 122 20 0,
n 125 8 134 17 0,
g 136 5 145 17 0,
"
(couldn't get it on sperate lines, so each comma is the start of a new line)

Now, the last part is completely fine. But in the first part, there is the "♀" sign, and when converted to list, it is "\n\x0c".
That is the part that I'm wondering about, and don't understand. I'm mostly doing this project for fun and learning. So if anyone could explain to me what it means/is, that would be great:).
And if I forgot some crucial information, please let me know (new user)

Answer (score 1):

If you upsample:

```py
img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=2, fy=2)
```

[image]

and if you apply [simple-threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html):

```py
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

[image]

Now if you read:

```py
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(thr))
```

Result:

```
Done Canceling
```

You can get the same result with [0.3.7](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/)

Make sure to read: [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html).

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("hocpQ.png")

# Up-sample
img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=2, fy=2)

# Convert to the gray-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Simple-threshold
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# OCR
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(thr))

# Display
cv2.imshow("result", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I tried this, but got this result in the console: 1pTolat-mOt-lalet-} late)
♀. I experimented a bit with it, and it seems to happen after i resize the picture

Comment: What is your pytesseract version?

Comment: The one installed with pip: 0.3.7, and I installed the newest from the tess github: tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20201127.exe (64 bit) resp. (additional info: I work in VS Code)

Comment: It tells the reason `v5.0.0-alpha`. Alpha refers that the new version is still in development. Why not using a stable version? When it turns stable version then use v5.0.0-stable.

Comment: "We don't provide an installer for Tesseract 4.1.0 because we think that the latest version 5.0.0-alpha is better for most Windows users", and it was the first download that matched I could find.  But should I download "tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v4.1.0.20190314.exe"?

Comment: They say it "latest version 5.0.0-alpha is better for most Windows users". What will non-windows user will do? I told you it is an experimental version. Who cares the system that will work best for windows? Anyway, if you are planning to use pip-version [0.3.7](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) then I can help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output

...

xconfig = '--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'

x1 = pytesseract.image_to_data(image, output_type=Output.DICT, config=xconfig)

print("value: ", int(x1["text"][4]))
```

output --> `value:  6`

Answer (score 0):

for your config all you need to have is

```
xconfig = "-c page_separator=''"
```

for some reason pytesseract has it on by default.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract as tes

tes.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

xconfig = "-c page_separator=''"
img = cv2.imread("DoneCheck.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
G = []
print(tes.image_to_string(img, config=xconfig))
G.append(tes.image_to_string(img, config=xconfig))
print(G)

hImg, wImg,_ = img.shape
boxes = tes.image_to_boxes(img)

for b in boxes.splitlines():
    print(b)
    b = b.split(' ')
    #print(b)
    x,y,w,h = int(b[1]), int(b[2]), int(b[3]), int(b[4])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, hImg-y), (w, hImg - h), (0, 0, 255), 1)

cv2.imshow("result", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

i found the answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276440/why-does-tesseract-append-l-to-the-output